# CakePHP Error: Missing view for Media viewclass

Tags: php, cakephp

Here is my function to download the uploaded files:

```
       public function download() {

       $this->viewClass = 'Media'; 

        $params = array(
        'id'        => 'article.pdf',
        'name'      => 'article',
        'download'  => true,
        'extension' => 'pdf',
        'path'      =>  WWW_ROOT . DS . 'files' . DS 
    );

 $this->set($params);
}
```

However calling this function results in the following error message:

Error: Media could not be found.

Error: Create the class Media below in file: src\View\Media.php

Any suggestions what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestions what is wrong with my code?

Yes:

1. Wrong CakePHP Version (3.x) for what you try to use
2. And even in 2.x [Media view is deprecated since 2.3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) as the documentation *clearly* states on top of the page: `Deprecated since version 2.3: Use Sending files instead.`

**[Read the documentation!](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)**

Taken from the link above:

```
public function sendFile($id)
{
    $file = $this->Attachments->getFile($id);
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
    // Return response object to prevent controller from trying to render
    // a view.
    return $this->response;
}
```

And *always* put the **exact** CakePHP version you're using in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> **Error: Create the class Media below in file: src\View\Media.php**

Create file in

1. Path - **src/View/**
2. File Name - **media.php**

Comment: Wrong version of Cake and Media view has been deprecated since 2.3. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html

Comment: if he using 2.0 it doesn't matter i think/

Comment: It does, read the link or my answer. And just by creating the view class he won't magically get the functionality he wants.

Comment: Actually I am using CakePHP 3. So just creating an empty file media.php would be enough?

Comment: It didnt help: Error: Create the class Media below in file: src\View\Media.php...